# What is the most appropriate tool to develop a new font for LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, tools

I need to design a couple of fonts to supplement the [archaic](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/archaic/) package. What is the most appropriate current tool to use? Is METAPOST/METAFONT still an option? I am neither a Bezier curve artist not a graphic designer, so anything that I can use programmatically is preferred.

Comment: Please do not reintroduce the `latex` tag: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365/what-to-do-with-the-latex-tag

Comment: @Caramdir Oops! Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) is said to be state-of-the-art.

Comment: I know near zero about making LaTeX fonts (assuming you mean type1 fonts with metrics, map files, fd files and so on), but FontForge can be used for almost any advanced font development job, it supports type1 and can even read and write TFM, AFM, and map files.

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested programmability, then you should try MetaType1 which is Metafont-like Metapost-based system for building Type1 fonts, developed and used by GUST font team.

Comment: I know of only one other use of the MetaType1 system; I'd be interested to hear if it's easy to get started.

Comment: I don't know myself, I never used it, but I plan to do one day (I've a geometric Arabic font that would benefit of the parametrisation).